# Can I run Dota 2 on ubuntu which is already on windows?

Tags: windows, steam

I have Ubuntu along with windows 7.And I have Dota 2 installed on windows 7.
Is there any way I can run dota 2 on Ubuntu without installing it again on Ubuntu (with windows steam library).
PS: I have installed steam on Ubuntu.

Comment: Probably you can't because this Dota 2 would be only for Windows and you require the Linux version. But try to include it in your library.

Comment: well it worked. I didn't have to do anything.
i just went to steam store, click on download dota2 and when it asked where do i want to install dota2, I chose the steam library directory of windows. It automatically detected dota2 and installed a update of 50mb and some files and its working completely fine :D

Comment: Wow thats good, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who are facing the same problem.
Here is the solution. You don't have to actually do anything.

1. Download steam on Ubuntu.
2. Search for dota2 in steam store.
3. click on download
4. when asked to where to download the game, select your steam library of windows.
5. It will automatically detect Dota2, download some files for Linux support (maybe 100mb).
6. It will show game under library under Linux + win OS.

PS: Your other windows partitions (where your steam library is located) should be mounted.

:)

Comment: Saves up a lot of space on my ubuntu. This is perfect!